# Stretch image in toast programmatically

Tags: android

I want to stretch the image to full screen or match width.Pro-grammatically in a toast. 
Currently all it does are wrap content.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    //imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    //imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
public void toast(View v){
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(imageView);
    toast.show();
}}
```

As you all can see, have tried all setAdjustViewBounds, FIT XY, FIT CENTRE
Can anyone give a hint on how to make this possible?

Comment: The above code is to be used in a service.
And the get layout inflater cannot be resolve in a service class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom toast, with following way. You can use image view instead of text view.

custom_toast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@color/design_text_background_color_argb">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_toast_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/activity_title_color"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use the following code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_text);
text.setText(error);

if (myInvalidPremiumToast != null)
    myInvalidPremiumToast.cancel();

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Hi Jaspreet, thanks for your answer, but I do not want to use the layout inflater.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image_4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

// java code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test,
(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));
```